# Snowflake cycle through values in column with loop

Tags: loops, variables, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cycle

I have a table with a bunch of columns, and I'm trying to write a loop that will cycle through each column each value and bring back a table like below:

| COLUMN_NM | COLUMN_VAL | COLUMN_VOL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Column_A | Avalue1 | 54 |
| Column_A | Avalue2 | 1 |
| Column_A | NULL | 5 |
| Column_B | Bvalue1 | 4 |
| Column_B | Bvalue2 | 21 |
| Column_B | Bvalue3 | 12 |
| Column_B | NULL | 23 |

I have so far created a temp table into which I pulled all the column names:

```
create temporary table z_cl (column_nm varchar)
;

insert into z_cl (column_nm) 
    select
        distinct f.KEY
    from
        (
            SELECT
                TOP 10 OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) AS json_payload
            FROM
                table_to_be_QAd
        ),
        LATERAL FLATTEN (input => json_payload) f
;
```

the table looks like this:

| COLUMN_NM |
| --- |
| Column_A |
| Column_B |
| Column_C |
| Column_D |

I've also created another one for the end result:

```
create temporary table z_qa (
    column_nm varchar,
    column_val varchar,
    column_vol int
)
;
```

This is where I'm stuck. So far I've read through the Snowflake documentation as well as looked at a number of different solutions ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71549976/snowflake-data-unloading-multiple-tables/71552286#71552286)) but I can't seem to get my head around how cursors and other type variables work within loops. I have tried to put the below (that gives me the exact desired output format but only for one column):

```
set col = 'Column_A'
;

insert into z_qa (column_nm, column_val, column_vol)

select $col as column_nm
,IDENTIFIER($col) as column_val
,count(*) as column_vol
from table_to_be_QAd
group by IDENTIFIER($col)
;
```

into a FOR loop like so:

```
declare 
c1 cursor for select column_nm from z_cl;
col varchar;

begin
    
    for record in c1 do
    set col = record.column_nm;
    
    insert into z_qa (column_nm, column_val, column_vol)
    select $col as column_nm
    ,IDENTIFIER($col) as column_val
    ,count(*) as column_vol
    from table_to_be_QAd
    group by IDENTIFIER($col)
    ;
    
    end for;
end;
```

The error message I'm getting is

> "Error: Session variable '$COL' does not exist (line 41)"

Removing the $ doesn't help. What are the flaws in my approach, what could I do differently?

Thank you!

Comment: Edited to fix table formatting.

Comment: You are declaring variable in Declare section col varchar; and expecting this as Session Variable. If you want Col as Session variable then do not declare it under Declare section, just make statement like this

Comment: Edited to fix missing word from syntax and because I forgot to swap out one of the table names with the desensitized version.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring variable in Declare section col varchar; and expecting this as Session Variable. If you want Col as Session variable then do not declare it under Declare section, just make statement like this Set Col=record.column_nm;  and remove that variable from declare section.

```
declare 
c1 cursor for select column_nm from z_cl;


begin
    
    for record in c1 do
    set col = record.column_nm;
    
    insert into z_qa (column_nm, column_val, column_vol)
    select $col as column_nm
    ,IDENTIFIER($col) as column_val
    ,count(*) as column_vol
    from fact_paid_media_display
    group by IDENTIFIER($col)
    ;
    
    end for;
end;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but this does not work, I've tried it already. It gives the same error message with or without having col in the declare section. I have also edited my post because I left out the word "col" from the set statement, whereas the actual code I'm trying to run had it correctly, sorry about that.

Comment: Just discovered that you can't set Session Variable Inside Anonymous block ; You can set that before anonymous block  and that works while accessing through Anonymous block.

Comment: if I need to set the variable outside the block, then how do I cycle through the list of values that variable will need to take? In other words I can't set the variable value outside the block because it's through the loop that the variable would get its value in the first place. @akshindesnowflake

Comment: In that case don't use Session Variable , Use normal Variables instead

Comment: what would that look like in the above example? According to https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables there is no difference as far as variables defined via SQL is concerned.